# Passing by value a type struct to a function, Error:two or more data types in declaration of 'average'!! -

Tags: c++, function, struct

Hello to all that read

I have a small problem(or it could be large!), just one error at compile time but as  we all know one error is all it takes to hinder progress.
Basically I am fairly new to C++ and have been tasked with writing the following code and passing by value a type stuct argument to the function. But I get the following error message:
"two or more data types in declaration of average" so any solution/s to my one error would be much appreciated. 
Many thanks in advance...

```
enter code here
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


           struct student{

              char name[40];
              int student_id;
              int student_grades[3];
              int average;
           };

int main ()
{
   extern int average(student);
   student programming;

   int j;

         cout<<"\nPlease Enter the student name for student number: ";

         cin>>programming.name;

         cout<<"\nPlease Enter student i.d for student number: ";

         cin>>programming.student_id;

         cout<<"\nPlease Enter student grades for student number: ";

         for(j=0;j<3;j++){

                    cout<<"\nEnter student grade no: "<<j+1<<"\n";
                    cin>>programming.student_grades[j];               
         }

         programming.average=average(programming);

         cout<<"\nNo.      Name      ID Number      Average\n";
         cout<<programming.name;
         cout<<"      "<<programming.student_id <<"      ";
         cout<<programming.average<<"      ";             

     system ("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}

struct student;
int void average(student programming){

    int sum=0;
    int ave=0;
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
           sum=sum+programming.student_grades [j];
    }
    ave=sum/3;
    return ave;
}
enter code here
```

Comment: You seem to be very confused. I can't even tell what you're expecting certain things to do in your code.

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of a `char` array for the name.

Comment: "int void average()" ???? what is this supposed to mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this?

```
int void average(student programming){
```

That's "two or more types" in a row, in the part where you say what the return type is for the function. Make up your mind.

There are several other problems with your code, mostly just stylistic. You don't want your function declaration to be `extern` (since it's right there in the same file); you want that declaration to be outside of main (it will work inside, but there's really no point); you don't need `math.h` (which is a C header anyway); you should be using a real string type to represent strings; storing the grade average back into the structure isn't especially useful (you already have it, so just use it directly); and several of your variable names don't make any sense (`programming` is an especially obvious example).

Comment: Yes- points taken, I will examine in detail what you have said and try to learn. Many thanks a tick for you.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on"you should be using real string types to represent strings"? like an example...

Comment: The `std::string` class from the `<string>` library.

Answer (score 2):

`int void average(student programming)` is not a valid syntax. There is only one return type, i.e. it should be `int average(student programming)`.

Comment: Many Thanks...It was the "void" that I forgot to take out. Silly me! A reputation tick for you for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of your average function should be:

```
int average(student programming)
```

You've got an extra "void" in there.